# WARN: Chef client 21056 is running, will wait for it to finish and then run

Tags: chef-infra

I've added a basic recipe to my chef-client cookbook which is, in turn, included in the role:

```
package "hadoop-cdh4.4.0-conf-prod" do 
    action :install
end
```

After running it on my test node, I did not get any error or any indication that it's being installed. When I tried re-running "chef-client", I received the following:

```
WARN: Chef client 21056 is running, will wait for it to finish and then run.
```

Does it mean the package is being installed in the background?

Comment: We need more details on your setup, is chef clietn running as a service, what is the run list, what is the output of the chef run...

Comment: Here is what the output looks like:

 knife node show hdp-046.xxx.gbl


Node Name:   hdp-046.xxx.gbl
Environment: _default
FQDN:        hdp-046.xxx.gbl
IP:          10.60.140.66
Run List:    role[chef-client]
Roles:       chef-client
Recipes:     chef-client, chef-client::default, chef-client::service, chef-client::init_service
Platform:    ubuntu 14.04

I tried removing the chef-client as it's redudant but it would not go away:

knife node run list remove hdp-046.xxx.gbl "recipe[chef-client]"


I've added the hadoop_node recipe to the chef-client cookbook and uploaded it to the chef server

Comment: Edit your question instead. And a log of the run would really help

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that process ID 21056 is a currently running chef-client process.  As soon as that instance of chef-client completes, your call to chef-client will run.  Chef doesn't allow multiple instances of the client to run at the same time, as it can cause bad side effects.